# make root beer in the toilet

Tags: meaning

From the movie [Jurassic World (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_World).

Two boys wandered off into a restricted area for tourists to take a closer look at other dinosaur species that live in the park. While they're out there, their aunt, who's the president of the park, is ringing alarm bells at the control room to find them. Here's the two boys' short conversation:

> — Great idea.
>   — No! We're gonna get arrested. They'll shave our heads, and we're
>   gonna have to **make root beer in the toilet**.
>   — What are you talking about?

What's that he saying about making root beer in the toilet? I don't understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prisoners in the United States are, not surprisingly, prohibited alcohol.  Prisoners are an enterprising lot, and they have found a great many ways to get around that prohibition, most notably via **[pruno](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pruno)**, a homemade wine made by mixing anything fermentable (sugar, fruit, bread, ketchup) in a plastic bag and waiting a few days.  The resulting alcoholic beverage is often hidden in the toilet.

In the movie, the boy who is worried says that he'll have to make *root beer*, a traditional (occasionally homemade) soda, in the toilet after he is arrested.

Comment: Cute. Cuz they're minors, you know, and wouldn't dare make real hooch, even in prison!  I saw the movie, (Jurassic World) but never caught that line.

Comment: Excellent answer! +1 A non-drinker like me would have never got it! :)